# Query MongoDb sublists with C# LINQ regex

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to query a mongodb collection using regular expressions. I would like to use the MongoDb C# driver for LINQ expression tree parsing. This works fine with IsMatch on direct fields, but it silently returns nothing if I query fields on contained lists. I suspect that this is a bug in the driver, but perhaps someone know a workaround. I know that I could write some Bson queries that would do the job, but I would prefer to decouple Mongo from the queries where possible and only use plain LINQ.

For example. Lets say I have a list of cars, some of which come in both "Blue" and "Blueish".

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Colors;
}
```

I could query the name something like this:

```
 var regex = new Regex("^Volvo.*");
 var matchingCars = carCollection.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x.Name));
```

But if I try to query the colors, I get nothing:

```
 var regex = new Regex("^Blue.*");
 var matchingCars = carCollection.Where(x => x.Colors.Any(y => regex.IsMatch(y)));
```

Running both expressions on a plain C# `List<Car>` works as expected, but only the Name query works with the Mongo LINQ driver.

Any explanations or workarounds?

I am aware that I can write a mongo-specific bson-query, but I would prefer to use plain LINQ.

Actual project code (models is an IQueryable):

```
 models = models.Where(x => x.UniqueVehidleIds.Any(y => regex.IsMatch(y)));
```

Comment: In `carCollection.Where(x => x.Colors.Any(y => regex.IsMatch(x.Name)));`  you're not using Colors but Car. Should `regex.IsMatch(x.Name)` be `regex.IsMatch(y)` instead? `x` is a car not a color -- you should be using `y` instead.

Comment: bad example, will correct

Comment: A workaround would be to use StartsWith -> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslatorTests.cs#L170.